# Freeze headers in react-admin `List` component

Tags: react-admin

Some of my users like to have 100 list items visible, to suit their workflow.

But, when scrolling down, they no longer see the column headers.

Is it possible to `freeze the headers` in a List component, so that the table scrolls, but the headers remain visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the `react-admin` `DataGrid` component has sticky headers.

The code in question code had custom CSS that prevented the sticky header behaviour.